# Получение названия переменной через ее значение (не словарь)

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная `p1w = [0, 0]`, мне нужно реализовать код, который по значению переменной сможет как-то сослаться на ее название или вывести его.

Comment: `if p1w == [0,0] : print('p1w')`

Comment: Мне неизвестно имя переменной, нужно ввести значение, чтобы по итогу вывелось название переменной, которой выдано это значение.

Comment: а точно нужно именно это? В программировании вряд ли есть задачи, когда нужно получить имя переменной по ее содержанию. Скорее всего вы что-то себе придумали, что делает более простым и понятным способом без вот такой акробатики

Comment: Ну у меня есть переменная с координатами, и с этой переменной нужно связать другую переменную, в которой собраны так сказать "пути". Для этого мне нужно было получить название переменной и через eval() провернуть кое-что

Comment: не нужно тут не имя переменной, не eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей программе может быть более чем одна переменная с таким значением.
Здесь выводятся все такие имена переменных:

```
variables = vars().copy()
for name, value in variables.items():
    if type(value) == list and value == [0, 0]:
        print(name)
```

Встроенная функция `vars()` возвращает словарь всех имен с их значениями.

Comment: for name, value in variables.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Исправил - в первой команде добавил `.copy()`.

Comment: Да тип можно не проверять. Конкретному списку будет равен только такой же список.

Comment: @CrazyElf, тип **должно** проверить, иначе для сравнивания `value == [0, 0]` может для других переменных возникнуть `ValueError`. Проверите.